# Attached apk file remains non updated

Tags: android, apk, email-attachments, android-build

I am facing this problem so many times,

I used to send the apk files through mail to my clients for reviewing.

Sometimes , they are telling that the new attached one has not get any updates , it remains same.

Even i did updates in that and, i have chacked it by uninstalling the older application and downloaded the attachment , So it was working fine with updates in myside.

I asked them to do same. But for them it wasn't.

So please give some idea,

1. Is there any better way to share the apk files?
2. Are they need to clean some other folders in their mobile, like "temp and cache" in PC?.
3. Or I missed somewhere in the Updated builds?

Please it is very difficult one for me to face always.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try by increasing Version ID and Version Name every time you build. Make sure you are using the same signature key for every build.

Comment: @NyanLH : I won't change keys always. Increasing Version ID is a good idea, thanks. But i want to know that whether the older file sits somewhere in the mobile folders?... Do we have any ways to cleanup the cache and temp like the PC... Thanks again for your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm.. instead of sending the .apk file to them through email, why not upload your .apk file to a server or website folder and let them install from there using their phone / device.
in android, you can install apk files from the internet right :)

that way, you can just send them the link of the updated version of your app.

Maybe the problem there is your apk sent to their computers, is either not really saved / not overwritten. in case the .apk file has same filename.

you can try to change file name also

:)

Comment: Thanks, Changing the file name every time isn't gud idea for me. I can upload it on a server. 

In my case they are not using computers to download, directly they are download to device from mail. If server links or computers downloads are needs to be cleared their cache, i dont want to tak dis risk. Thats y i send it thru mail and asked them to download it directly to the device...